# After array initialization in dafny assertion fail

Tags: computer-science, verification, dafny

I'm trying to get into dafny, however I can't wrap my head around the following:

```
var a := new int[10];
var i := 0;
while i < 10
  decreases 20 - i 
{
  a[i] := i;
  i := i+1;
}
assert a[5] == 5;
```

So fairly simply stuff so far: Declare new array a and initialize it's values with the respective index-positions. Thus the assert statement should be true, however dafny complains with "assertion violation". I have tried comparing a[5] to other numbers, e.g. 4 and 6 and some others in close proximity, yet it didn't work, i wonder why?

Related to this I would like to ask how *print* works in dafny (using VSCode)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the verifier is failing here, you have to understand how the Dafny verifier handles `while` loops. In short, the verifier is not allowed to "look into" the body of a while loop when attempting to prove an assertion that is outside the body.

In order to reason about while loops in Dafny, you will need to apply loop invariants, which the tutorial can probably explain better than me: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide

I would suggest looking at the `Find` example in particular for something similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I simply forgot about loop invariants, thank you very much!